# How to replace github,io page

Tags: github, github-pages

I deleted my github.io repository and created a new one. It doesn't appear on link.

I waited for 15 minutes:
https://github.com/yeras-is/yeras-is.github.io

I excepted it will appear in few minutes as it was in first time, but it does not...

Comment: It's appearing for me. Have you tried a hard refresh on your browser?

Comment: https://yeras-is.github.io/   it doesn't appear on this link

Comment: I can see content as well in the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you delete old repository for github pages and create new one, you should set custom not-real url for git page. wait 2 minute and truncate url. Then is will appear on your github io url